# Laravel Schedule not sending email

Tags: php, laravel, cron

It's my first time trying to implement Task Scheduling, I'm trying to send automatic E-mails at a certain time:

Before implementing my cron I first tested my email sending code manually in a normal class to see if there is no error, and there was no error, the email was sent successfully.

After that, I started implementing the Task Scheduling

**Democron.php**

```php
protected $signature = 'demo:cron';

    protected $description = 'Command description';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

 
    public function handle()
    {
        
        $tasks = Task::all();
        $date = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
        
        foreach ($tasks as $task) {
            if($task->completed_at != null){
                $validad = $task->completed_at;
                $receiver_id =  User::findOrFail($task->user_id);
                if($date > $validad){
                    $details = [
                        'task_id' =>$task->id,
                        'receiver_id' => $receiver_id
                    ];
                    
                    $subject = 'TeamWork - Você tem tarefas em atraso!';
                    $view = 'emails.project.delaydtask';
                    Mail::to($receiver_id->email)->send(new SendMail($details, $subject, $view));
                    Log::info('Email enviado com sucesso para '.$receiver_id->email);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

**Kernel.php**

```php
protected $commands = [
        DemoCron::class,
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('demo:cron')
                 ->twiceDaily(12, 15)
                 ->timezone('Africa/Maputo');
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');
     
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
```

I added to **CRON JOBS on CPANEL**
and set twiceDaily at 12 and 15

```
  /usr/local/bin/php /.......myProjectPath/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I printed a LOG in my DemoCron.php to see if it really works

**Result 1:** when I select schedule once per minute it prints my LOG respecting all the conditions that are in my **Democron.php** , but it *doesn't send the email*.

**Result 2:** When I select a certain time (Twice per day or once a day) my LOG does not print anything and it *does not send the email*.

What am I doing wrong? Help me please!

**UPDATE**

my SendMail class that i use to send emails manually works perfectly,

but the scheduled emails are not going

```php
class SendMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $details, $subject, $view;

    public function __construct($details, $subject, $view)
    {
        $this->details = $details;
        $this->subject = $subject;
        $this->view = $view;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject($this->subject)
                    ->view($this->view, ['details' => $this->details]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying several times I found a workaround.

**1- create a new controller**

I created a new controller called **MailController** instead of using the Kernel.php and Democron.php classes that I generated through Laravel Scheduling

```php
class MailController extends Controller
{
    public function delayedtask(){
        try {
            
            $tasks = Task::all();
            $date = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
            
            foreach ($tasks as $task) {
                if($task->completed_at != null){
                    $validad = $task->completed_at;
                    $receiver_id =  User::findOrFail($task->user_id);
                    if($date > $validad){
                        $details = [
                            'task_id' =>$task->id,
                            'receiver_id' => $receiver_id
                        ];
                        
                        $subject = 'TeamWork - Você tem tarefas em atraso!';
                        $view = 'emails.project.delaydtask';
                        Mail::to($receiver_id->email)->send(new SendMailQueue($details, $subject, $view));
                        Log::info('Email enviado com sucesso para '.$receiver_id->email);
                    }
                }
            }

            return "Done!";

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                return "Something went wrong!";
            }
    }
}
```

**2-add a new route**

added a new route without Auth

```php
Route::get('/delayedtask',[MailController::class, 'delayedtask']);
```

**3-Added a cronjob on Cpanel**

```
   curl -s "https://myWebsiteURL/delayedtask">/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

**First of all lets check all things:**

- Verify your mail configurations in your .env;
- Verify in your email class if have `implements ShouldQueue`;
- If you are implementing ShouldQueue, you must have to verify too your queue´s configuration in .env;
- If is not implementing ShouldQueue, don´t miss time verifying queue´s config;

**All right all things validated and still not sending email:**

- Add the Send mail in try catch and log the catch if something went wrong;
- If don´t log nothing in try catch, try to create an command that just send a simple email;
- If dosen´t work try to send an email by your mail in Cpanel, because this should be the problem;

**Finally**

- In my cases using cPanel, I always create the croon task to all seconds like  `*   *   *   *   *` and in the kernel of my laravel project I verify  if some command must be executed with the laravel commands like `->twiceDaily(12, 15)`.

Try all things and if the error still, please update this thread!

Comment: Hi @samuel, thanks for your collaboration, all my sending email configuration are fine, because i tested to send the email manualy and it works, when i add a try-catch the LOG does not print nothing

Answer (score 0):

For me it was my apache config file (php.ini)

I initially followed the recommended "disable_functions" configuration that ConfigServer said to do, and that's what caused the issue for me. Thankfully I recently did this change and remembered, otherwise I would've never figured it out

Looks like adding proc_open in the disabled_functions causes this

Open up your php.ini and find "disable_functions", then delete/remove "proc_open" from that list

All I had to do was save the file and my schedule instantly worked, didn't have to restart anything - but you may need to try to restart yours

Hope this helps anyone else who comes across this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem,
i tried a new smtp email server

```
MAIL_HOST=pro.eu.turbo-smtp.com

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

instead of

```
MAIL_HOST=smtpauth.online.net

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

I don't know if it's about the encryption or host features,
but it worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).